# Compare LDAP Password with another value (ldap3, Python)

Tags: python, ldap, openldap, ldap3

I want to implement a comparison-function with ldap3 in Python that can compare a user-given value with a password stored in my ldap-entry.

This is easy to do with non-salted passwords but I'm struggling with salted ones.
For example, the stored password in my ldap-entry looks like this:

```
{SSHA}F5GwOd39wiK+jEKD6UwCs+9XvzvdRYlX
```

and represents the Salted SHA value of

```
testpassword
```

I do not want to check the value with a bind because there might be more than one password saved in the entry. A bind would only check if the user-given value is indeed one of the passwords, and not ***the*** password I want to compare it to.

Edit: I want to do this in a LDAP-Editor. A function like this is already implemented in the LDAP-Editor I'm currently using (LDAP Account Manager / LAM). This comparison is ***not*** there to handle a login of some sort, it is there so the user himself can check if the password matches his user-given value.

This would be perfect for entries that have more than one password (yes, that is possible) and you have to delete one of them. Of course you could delete all values and add back the ones you still want to use. A comparison would be handy here because the step of deleting every password and adding all the ones back that are still in use would be skipped.

If there is anything else to clarify, I can elaborate more.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is LDAP binding account required for user authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519666/is-ldap-binding-account-required-for-user-authentication)

Comment: "

I want to implement a comparison-function with ldap3 in Python that can compare a user-given value with a password stored in my ldap-entry.": no you don't. You want to implement the LDAP bind operation such that the LDAP server does the checking. THe LDAP server will check all the `userPasswort` entries. NB There is no [tag:encryption] here: passwords are securely hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: @user207421 I edited my post. I'm not talking about a comparison when logging in of some sort. I also wrote that binding does not help me here, I dont think that you read my post completely.

Comment: I didn't read the part that you have now edited in, because you hadn't written it yet. Why a user would need to check that his password equals his password is another mystery. In any case he can't, because of password hashing.

Comment: Sorry, but I already wrote that I dont need the binding operation before I edited my question. I just edited it to make it extra clear to people like you.
You kind of sound elitist, the password compare function is integrated into our current LDAP-Editor, so there might be demand for it.
Maybe you shouldnt be so bitter about a question in an online forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDAP faq-o-matic [explains how to generate SSHA password hashes](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html)). Using that information, we know how to extract the salt from the SSHA password, which then allows us to hash our test password using the same salt to see if we get the same digest:

```py
import sys
import base64
import hashlib

SSHA_TAG = '{SSHA}'

def salt_from_ssha(pw):
    if pw.startswith(SSHA_TAG):
        pw = pw[len(SSHA_TAG):]
    dec = base64.b64decode(pw)
    digest, salt = dec[:20], dec[20:]
    return digest, salt

def compare_password_with_hashed_password(hashed_password, plaintext_password):
    digest, salt = salt_from_ssha(hashed_password)
    plaintext_hash = hashlib.sha1(plaintext_password + salt)
    return plaintext_hash.digest() == digest


target = sys.argv[1]

while True:
    testpw = input("Enter a test password: ").encode()
    if compare_password_with_hashed_password(target, testpw):
        print("You found it!")
        break
```

Running this might look like:

```
$ py hasher.py {SSHA}F5GwOd39wiK+jEKD6UwCs+9XvzvdRYlX
Enter a test password: foo
Enter a test password: bar
Enter a test password: testpassword
You found it!
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for! I will definitley check this out. I did not find the forum post you linked, thank you for that, too.